# Can't print property in array - Mongoose

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

I have a model `Player`, containing a `slug` string, `name` string and `nickname` array. In nickname array, I will store `nickname` models. I create a player with a name and and a slug, then I create each `nickname` models one by one and push them to `player.nickname`. Then I save `player` and return it as callback result.

When I print it to console, it's like this:

```
{ name: 'Max Zaslofsky',
  nickname: ["{ _id: 56a35c2b33a41a8c187efd08, nickname: 'Slats', __v: 0 }"] }
```

Then I try to print its name and its nicknames:

```
    let player = results.findRandomPlayer;
    let nicknames = player.player_nickname;
    console.log("Player is", player.name);
    console.log("His nickname is:");
    _.forEach(nicknames, function (nickname) {
        console.log(nickname.nickname);
    });
```

But it prints to console:

```
Player is  Max Zaslofsky
His nickname is:
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: player.player_nickname should not exists. player.nickname should.

Comment: @chriskelly you're right. however, this time console logs `undefined`.

Comment: store nickname as an object. see answer below . But I don't understand why a down vote for the answer, could anyone explain a bit?

Answer (score 0):

From what you have written, nickname contains an array of unparsed json object strings.

You code should look like this:

```
let player = results.findRandomPlayer(); // invoke function!
let nicknames = player.nickname; // use correct propertyname

console.log("Player is", player.name);
console.log("His nickname is:");

_.forEach(nicknames, function (nickname) {
    // its not an object its an unparsed object
    console.log(JSON.parse(nickname).nickname);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

At nickname array you are pushing string instead of object. Remove the double quote `" "`, i mean store the nickname as an object instead of string. You can use `JSON.parse(nicknameString)`

{

```
  name: 'Max Zaslofsky',
  nickname: ["{ _id: 56a35c2b33a41a8c187efd08, nickname: 'Slats', __v: 0 }"] }
```

Should be

```
{ 
  name: 'Max Zaslofsky',
  nickname: [{ _id: 56a35c2b33a41a8c187efd08, nickname: 'Slats', __v: 0 }]
}
```

Comment: You can't convert a json string to object by removing quotes. Use JSON.parse as I already explained in my answer

Comment: Sorry I was thinking about storing the data as an object instead of string.
`{ _id: 56a35c2b33a41a8c187efd08, nickname: 'Slats', __v: 0 }`. So that you actually don't have to parse json. Look at the json string, before storing he is converting the object to string `JSON.stringify(obj)` . @chriskelly

Comment: Your solution is absolutely correct. But it's not the only one way to solve it, am i right? @chriskelly